# React Redux state working differently in production

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my React/Redux app, I have a component with a conditional that checks if a reducer state value is empty or not. When running in development mode, this condition works exactly as intended - on reducer's state changes, the conditional returns the expected result. However, when I build the app for deployment, the conditional no longer reacts to the state change, so the code behind the conditional is fired when it shouldn't be. What could be causing this discrepancy between dev and production?

Here's the function with the conditional:

```
_showNav = () => {
    const { selectedItem } = this.props
    if ( selectedItem !== "" ) {
        return (
            <Navigation/>
        )
    }
}
```

The function is called within render() by a single line:

```
{this._showNav()}
```

Comment: You need to provide a fully reproducible example and if you can't, I suggest using Redux DevTools extension to debug all these things.

Comment: Is `{this._showNav()}` what you get from babel's transpiled file it creates?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve it, I moved the conditional into the Navigation component. I'm not exactly sure why this worked, but I am assuming that by moving the logic further down the component tree, it was more likely to pick up on state changes.